# scilab - Writing multiple images to a single folder

Tags: image-processing, scilab

I am working in `Scilab 5.5.2`. I need to write multiple images to a single folder. The images which I want to write are cropped images from a set of inputs. I am able to write a single image to the folder with the following command:

```
imwrite(fname,strcat('C:\Users\dell\Desktop\example_sci\myfolder\1.jpg'));
```

I have put this in a for loop, so the output image is over written and the result is a single image.

How can i write all the results to a single folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the paths like this.

```
for j=1:10
   pathname = "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\example_sci\myfolder\"+ string(j) + ".jpg"
   xs2jpg(gcf(), pathname); 
end
```

I usually use the `xs2*`-command to export a chosen figure. (I use scilab 5.5.0, which does not contain `imwrite` anymore.)