# Exporting a file with a variable name in Scilab

Tags: plot, filenames, scilab

Here is what im trying:

1. Plot a set of points
2. Export the plot
3. Alter the position of the points
4. Plot again
5. Export again
6. Alter the position again
7. ...

The Problem is that i can not create variable filenames for the exported Plots, so my Question is:

How could i export the plots with a filename that is dependant on a variable n for example?

```
xs2png(0,"C:\directionary\scilab\Frame_n.png")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in a loop:

```
for i = 1 : numberOfImages
    // 
    // manipulate data;
    //
    scf(i) // opens a new graphic window
    plot(data);
    xs2png("C:\directionary\scilab\Frame_"+ string(i) +".png");
end
```

The `scf` command selects the current figure. So you do not have to select the figure number in the `xs2png` command. Numbers get converted to strings by `string()` and strings can be brought together with `+`.

Comment: Similar posting: [writing multiple images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35644639/writing-multiple-images-to-a-single-folder-in-scilab)